# Making a hyperlink circle a tag?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm making a splash page, to let the users choose a language of the page, and I have a few tweaks that I just can't pull off...
I want the clickable surface of the link to be only inside the circle, currently it can be clicked outside of the circle. I saw that it could also be done with SVG but I never tried to implement SVG code so I went with link tags...

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gigamlat/o1z0Lxr3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="meni">
            <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="home.html"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_play_circle_outline_48px-128.png"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="home.html"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_play_circle_outline_48px-128.png"></a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>   
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url(http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/20b7c734-ef8e-438c-8d02-8353fbfd06cb/40bd6a7e-2809-4008-82da-d3c68a07f1ae.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 35%;

}

li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use image map for that.Please find [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/mjwy4vko/2/)

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="meni">
            <ul>
            <li>
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_play_circle_outline_48px-128.png" usemap="#iconmap1">
            <map name="iconmap1">
               <area shape="circle" coords="64,64,54" href="home.html" alt="replay icon">
             </map>
            </li>

            <li>
             <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_play_circle_outline_48px-128.png" usemap="#iconmap2">
            <map name="iconmap2">
               <area shape="circle" coords="64,64,54" href="home.html" alt="replay icon">
             </map>
            </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works, one little typo though, you didn't put iconmap1 (you put iconmap) in map name on the first link ;)

Comment: yes that's why edited my answer and posted updated fiddle link :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following

**CSS**

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background-image: url(http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/20b7c734-ef8e-438c-8d02-8353fbfd06cb/40bd6a7e-2809-4008-82da-d3c68a07f1ae.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .circle
    {
        width: 106px;
        height: 106px;
        border-radius: 155px;
        background-color: grey;
        top: 18px;
        left: 10px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .circleoutline
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 150px;
        -webkit-border-radius:150px;
        left: -11px;
        top: -11px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="circleoutline">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_play_circle_outline_48px-128.png">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eowp92zr/)**